# How to exclude (ignore) certain folders in vagrant rsync?

Tags: vagrant, rsync

I wish to run npm install in my vagrant virtual box.

But whenever I ran the npm install command, my rsync will execute. Since my host computer does not have node_modules installed, it simply remove the folder completely for me.

What do I need to do so that my vagrant rsync will ignore the node_modules folder?

I cannot have node_modules being rsynced into the guest machine because my host and guest are two different systems. So far my vagrantfile looks like this.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"

  config.vm.hostname = "localhost"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000

  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/home/vagrant/app"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = "web2"
    v.memory = "4096"
    v.cpus = 2
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME", "1"]
  end

  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/home/vagrant/app", type: "rsync", rsync_auto: true, rsync_exclude: ['node_modules*']
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision/setup.sh"

end
```

And I execute vagrant rsync via

```
vagrant rsync-auto
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the vagrant tag: VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`rsync__exclude` as well as `rsync__auto` takes 2 `_`

You need to rewrite your line as

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/home/vagrant/app", type: "rsync", rsync__auto: true, rsync__exclude: ['./node_modules*']
```

Comment: Nice - this actually works for me. I hate having to deal with the large file names that come with node_modules, when developing on my Ubuntu vagrant guest VM via my Windows 10 host.

Answer (score 1):

Step 3 on http://perrymitchell.net/article/npm-symlinks-through-vagrant-windows/ worked better for me in the end...

From the page:

> The steps are simple:
>
> 1. Delete the node_modules directory if it exists.
> 2. Create a directory called, say "node_modules_projectname" in the VM's home directory (~) (Some articles and posts recommend making the
>    directory in /tmp, but obviously this is cleared on reboot, so it may
>    not be an optimal experience for this type of thing).
> 3. Link a local node_modules dir from within the project's directory
>
>    `ln -s ~/node_modules_projectname /path/to/your-project/node_modules`
> 4. Install the packages in the project directory:
>
>    `npm install`

Comment: It's important to point out that these 4 steps are not sufficient. Without activating symlink support I get a protocol error.