# Sharing a venv directory in Vagrant

Tags: windows, macos, vagrant, python-venv

I have a Windows 10 guest managed by vagrant, and a python app directory synced:

```
#Vagrantfile
config.vm.synced_folder "../python_app", "/vagrant_data"
```

I want to have a `venv` in both OSX host and Windows guest, but get error when trying to create in the guest:

```
Error: Unable to create directory 'C:\\vagrant_data'
```

In the guest box, `C:\vagrant_data` contains the `python_app` files.

And it is symlinked to another directory in the guest:

```
 Directory of C:\

11/18/2020  03:34 PM    <DIR>          Users
etc...
11/18/2020  03:17 PM    <SYMLINKD>     vagrant [\\vboxsvr\vagrant]
11/18/2020  03:17 PM    <SYMLINKD>     vagrant_data [\\vboxsvr\vagrant_data]
```

I am able to create a file:

```
echo hello world > vagrant_data\hello.txt
```

Or a directory:

```
mkdir vagrant_data\removeme
```

These files appear in the host directory as well.

There isn't already a `Scripts` or `Lib` directory.

There *is*, however a `pyvenv.cfg` file, which contains details from the host (osx):

```
home = /usr/local/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.8.6
```

Despite that I have `py --version 3.9` in the guest, the home location will obviously be different.

Is a good solution to [exclude](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/rsync) specified files within the synced directory?

Another option is, of course to not sync at all and use the Git remote to pass files from the devbox to the test environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant's [rsync](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/rsync) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44352166/2223106)

> does a one-time one-way sync from the machine running to the machine being started by Vagrant.

What makes much more sense is to simple move the `venv` into a directory *above* the synced folder, like this:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../my_venv/python_app", "/my_venv/python_app"
```

(Syncing a folder that's next to, rather than within the one that the Vagrantfile is located in)

In this way, only the second directory is synced, but the first is created. So I `vagrant ssh` into the guest, `cd` into the directory *above* the synced one and create the `venv` there.